Hyperparameter Widget
Could you please inform me if there exists a widget designed for the purpose of conducting hyperparameter optimization? I attempted to locate such a tool, but regrettably, I was unable to find one.

Hi @Gerardo, welcome to the site. It is not clear what context you are referring to. Are you asking about Orange widgets?

Hi, yes. I am trying to implement GridSearchCV but I can´t find any widget for that purpose. I've tried programming the Python Script Widget as well but I couldn't manage to do it
